# No component found with scheme : jetty

Tags: apache, jboss, apache-camel, fuseesb

So I scoured the message boards and see some people that have bumped into this issue but usually it was due to a missing dependency in the POM file.

My case:

1. Running JBoss Fuse jboss-fuse-6.1.0.redhat-379
2. Apache Camel 2.14.1
3. Spring 3.2.8_RELEASE_1
4. Have the camel-jetty dependency in my POM file
5. Installed the feature in Karaf. Verified the feature is there in
   OSGI list and feature list.
6. jetty / 8.1.14.v20131031

Runs fine within eclipse.

So I have a context with the following rest configuration:

```
<camelContext id="FIRST-CAMEL-CONTEXT" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" streamCache="true">
     <restConfiguration component="jetty" bindingMode="json" port="8881" host="0.0.0.0">
          <dataFormatProperty key="prettyPrint" value="true"/>
     </restConfiguration>

    <rest path="/search" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
      <description>Get Search Results</description>
       <!-- this is a rest GET to find all users -->
      <post uri="/SearchHotels" outType="HotelsEnvelope.Response" type="HotelsEnvelope.Request">
        <description>Hotels</description>
        <to uri="bean:searchRequest?method=ReturnHotels(Exchange,${body},${headers})"/>
      </post>
    </rest>
  .....
  </camelContext>
```

the beans defined above as such:

```
<bean id="searchRequest" class="ICEPricelineSVC.SearchRequest" />
```

In the Bean I basically create a context and then send a request to a third party service like so:

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();

.....

String url = String.format("jetty:http://api.rezserver.com/api/hotel/getResultsWithCacheV2?function_type=get&format=xml&refid=%s&api_key=%s&currency=USD&latitude=%s&longitude=%s&radius=%s&check_in=%s&check_out=%s&adults=2&children=0&rooms=1&nearby=0&recent=0&promo=1&sort_by=most_popular&sort_order=ASC&limit=5000&offset=0&format=xml&function_type=get&poi_name=search&bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false",supplier.getCredentials().getRefid(),supplier.getCredentials().getKey(), request.getQryLocation().getLat().toString(), request.getQryLocation().getLng().toString(), request.getQryLocation().getRadius().toString(),formatter1.format(dateCheckIn), formatter1.format(dateCheckOut));


Exchange exchange = template.send(url, new Processor() {
                                  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
  exchange.setPattern(ExchangePattern.InOut);
  Message inMessage = exchange.getIn();
  Inits.setupDestinationURL(inMessage);

  // set the operation name 

  inMessage.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.GET);
}
});

.....
```

When the producer template sends I get the jetty error.

I have tried various things. One of which is injecting the ApplicationContext in the bean and getting the FIRST_CAMEL_CONTEXT bean to retrieve the context.  In that case the request seems to be sent but the exchange returned from the processor is null.

Again, this all works in eclipse.  I also noticed that when I deploy the bundle I see it adding the dependencies to the container.  Is there a good way to chase this?  I have resorted to using the HTPClient for now but would really like to understand why there seems to be a classpath issue when using the producer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss Fuse 6.1 comes with Apache Camel 2.12.x out of the box. You must use that version as that is the certified and tested version.

JBoss Fuse 6.2 which is the next release comes with Apache Camel 2.14.x and that release has the new rest-dsl.

Comment: Okay, When does that release drop?

Comment: FYI, Rolling back to 2.12.x doesn't resolve this.  Seems like this is just a bug when running within the framework.  Not sure why jetty is not found as it is an installed feature and on the classpath.